# How to dynamically select Interactive Grid rows by column value

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I currently want to be able to dynamically select rows of an interactive grid by passing csv of column values to a JS-code dynamic action.  Here is the code I have so far

```js
var columnName = 'CRITERIA_ID';
var targetValues = $v("P13_SELECTED_VALUES").split(";");
//P13_SELECTED_VALUES is set to 112:113:115 via a static assignment DA that occurs directly before this 
console.log(targetValues[1]);
console.log(targetValues[2]);
console.log(targetValues[3]);

var ig$ = apex.region("myIG_StaticID").widget();
var view = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");

view.model.forEach(function(record) {
  var columnValue = view.model.getValue(columnName, record);
  console.log("Column Value: " + columnValue);

  if (targetValues.includes(columnValue)) {
    view.grid.selection.add(record);
  }
});
```

When this is ran I don't get any errors in the console, but no selections occur.  The `console.log` lines that I added do get triggered but in every single case, instead of outputing the variables, they output 'undefined'.  This includes for the values of the `targetValues` array and the output of `columnValue` within the loop later on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it gets me to output the values I am attempting to check with my `console.log` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close - what I can see you would need 2 minor changes:

1. Start index with zero:

   console.log(targetValues[0]);
   console.log(targetValues[1]);
   console.log(targetValues[2]);
2. pass record first:

   var columnValue = view.model.getValue(record, columnName);

Edit: one more:

```
let recordSelection = [];
view.model.forEach(function(record) {
  var columnValue = view.model.getValue(record, columnName);
  console.log("Column Value: " + columnValue);

  if (targetValues.includes(columnValue)) {
    recordSelection.push(record);
  }
});
view.setSelectedRecords(recordSelection);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, the first of the two allowed the console logs to display the correct values but the second fix brought up the following error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selection')" at the view.grid.selection.add(record); line

Comment: You might try 'setSelectedRecords'. See edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to do exactly what I want it to